# Динамика шрифтов, CSS

Tags: html, css

подскажите пжл, есть ли в CSS возможность задавать размерность шрифта динамично?

Например есть текст,  на ПК в 20 пкс он смотрится нормально, но в те же  20 пкс на мобиле смотрится плохо и нужно задать 16пкс.

Можно ли задать одно конкретное значение,  например 16 пкс,  чтобы эта размерность адаптировалась сама под экран?

Спрашиваю про принцип работы как с 100vh 100vw,  только для размера шрифта.  Имеется ли такая возможность или мы вынуждены под каждое разрешение изменять это значение?

Answer (score 0):

Задайтесь единицы в rem она ровно размеру шрифта по умолчанию например шрифт документа 10px = 1em

Comment: Извините, rem или em?

Comment: по пробуйте и то и другой если фиксировать размер шрифта есть единиц pt